# Functions and transformations

Tags: algebra-precalculus, graphing-functions, transformation

> A function, $y = f(x)$, originally has a domain of $x ≥ 4$ and a range of $y ≤ 1$.
>
> Determine the new domain and range of $y=-2f(-x+5)+1$ after applying all transformations.
>
> (Try sketching the graph and applying the transformations,)

I am stuck with even starting this question without having the original function. But based on the domain and range of the original I think this is a square root parent function. I am at loss; please help. This question has been bugging me and I am sure I am overthinking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In keeping with your idea about using a square root parent function, I put into the graphing site Desmos a function $f$ with the desired domain and range: [**link**](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/gqnpf3thzp).

You will see there not only the original graph, but also a sequence of transformations that get to the final function that you are supposed to be considering. These are color coded, and you can click the color next to each function input to hide it.

Can you see how each of them affects the parent graph?

Here is an image for completeness:

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure why someone has: downvoted this answer, downvoted the original question, and voted to close the question. **FWIW:** Leaving a comment [in lieu of!] downvoting everything in sight can be a more effective way of communicating one's thoughts.

Comment: I am new to this system but from what I see, the response only has one vote and it is an upvote (which I provided). As for closing the question: I selected "accept this answer" as it was actually in accordance with another approach I took (I hope this did not affect the question being close as you said)

Comment: @AneQo Once you have sufficient reputation, you can see the breakdown of up/downvotes. In this particular case, I can see that there are two upvotes and two downvotes; so, the net votes visible is 0. But, I'm not sure why!

Comment: Your response looks fine to me and illustrates a good approach to the problem for students at this level. The original question was [mentioned in CRUDE](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/45579669#45579669), though, so I'd expect the question to go through their downvote/close/delete process.

Comment: @MarkMcClure Ah, thanks for the pointer; I figured some irregularity must exist.

Answer (score 0):

From the domain and the range of $f(x)$, we may know that $$-x+5 \geq 4, ~~~~~~ f(-x+5) \leq 1.$$

Thus, for the new function, the domain is $$x \leq 1,$$ and the range is $$y=-2f(-x+5)+1 \leq -2 \cdot 1+1=-1.$$

Comment: I think there is a sign error in your range.$f \le 1\Rightarrow -2f \ge -2 \Rightarrow -2f+1 \ge -1$